# Laravel Eloquent: Nested Relationship to save data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested, relationships

I want to save data on Token which has `mid` and `tid`

`mid` references to Merchant `id`

`tid` references to Terminal `id`

```php
class Merchant {
   public function terminal() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Terminal', 'tid');
    }

    public function token()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Token', 'mid');
    }
}

class Terminal {
       public function merchant() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Merchant::class);
    }

    public function token()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Token', 'tid');
    }
}

class Token {
    public function terminal()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Terminal::class);
    }

    public function merchant()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Merchant::class);
    }
}
```

Merchant hasMany(Terminal)
Terminal hasMany(Token)

```php
Merchant 
id
mid

Terminal
id
tid

Token
id
mid
tid
token

$merchant_info->terminal->token->save(new Token($data));
```

Throws an error:
`Method token does not exist.`

Comment: `token` doesn't exist in whatever `terminal` returns.

Comment: what should be the proper approach ?

Comment: please post your models with their relationships.

Comment: ok, the `terminal` relationship in your `merchant` will return a *collection*. you should get one from that first before accessing `token`. E.g., `$merchant->terminal->first()->token`

Comment: @Wreigh, `tid` works however `mid` has NULL value

Comment: Does `Merchant` also `hasMany(token)`? why the `Token` model has `mid`?